# Custom queries with Breeze JS (Fiql + Breeze)

Tags: breeze

Im new to breeze js, I understand that breeze has it's own query language related to OData
But I am trying to get breeze js working with a  custom query language, as an example FIQL is
one of the form to make queries to backend, can we get breeze run with this type of query language.

Overview of FIQL :-
http://jaxenter.com/tutorial-smarter-search-with-fiql-and-apache-cxf-46876.html

Answer (score 0):

(this is not a technical answer, at the very most it's an advice)

As mentionned from their [website documentation](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/introduction) :

> Today, out of the box, the Breeze product ships with adapters for the
>   ASP.NET Web API and for OData. It also ships with .NET components that
>   interface with the Entity Framework and that generate Breeze metadata
>   from an Entity Framework model; that EF model could be developed code
>   first or database first.  **The Breeze client is in no way limited to
>   these technologies; they are merely the first backend components
>   available; we’d be thrilled to help you adapt Breeze to your preferred
>   server stack**.

Answer (score 0):

First question is whether

- 1) you want breeze to actually create FICL queries on the client and send them to a FICL service.  This involves translating a client side breeze EntityQuery into FICL url syntax. If so you would need to create a new a 'uriBuilder' adapter.
- 2) you want to translate a breeze query already sent to your service into FIQL syntax on the server so that you can further refine the query and then send it on to your FICL service. If so you would need to create a breeze DataService endpoint.

Both of these are certainly possible.

If you are looking at the 1st option, take a look at the 'b000_uriBuilder.xxx' files in the breeze GitHub repo under the 'src' directory. There should be two 'uriBuilder.xxx' files, one which translates an EntityQuery into OData syntax and another that translates the EntityQuery into a new 'json' query syntax. There is also additional information on this 2nd syntax here:

http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/query-using-json

Both of these 'uriBuilder's make use an internal 'visitor' framework that we have not yet documented but should be reasonably understandable by looking at the source.

If you are looking at the 2nd option, I would recommend looking at the link mentioned above and then taking a look at the 'breeze.node.js' repo and the 'breeze-sequelize' subdir within it.  In this repo we take a serialized server side breeze EntityQuery and translate it into a 'Node' Sequelize query that we can apply to a variety of backends.

Another option is to contact our professional services arm, at breeze@ideablade.com and ask them to assist in building the adapters for you or to ask for more detailed technical help.